# to duplicate an image on mouse hover in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, mousehover

I have three images on the left top corner of the page. when i hover over any of the images, that image should appear in the center of the page enlarged. but the image should also be present at the original position i.e. at the left top corner. I am able to use CSS position and hover attributes to move the image in the center. But Don't know how to duplicate the image using html and css. The code i used is given below.

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <img src="assets\images\download.png" width="100" height="100" id="img1">
  <img src="assets\images\images.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="img2">
  <img src="assets\images\turtle-50.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="img3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

img:hover {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

Comment: I doubt if this can be done with css only.. I'm afraid you need some script for this.

Comment: any hints on how to do it with typescript?